# Run multiple Insert statements with dynamic schema name

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I want to run 100 Insert statements of the below Insert`s in a Script. The schema name db1 and db2 must used in the placeholder variable SourceDatabase and TargetDatabase.

```
DECLARE
SourceDatabase VARCHAR2(50) := 'DB1';
TargetDatabase VARCHAR2(50) := 'DB2';

BEGIN

Insert Into TargetDatabase.TableName (SELECT  * FROM SourceDatabase.TableName);
Insert Into TargetDatabase.TableName (SELECT  * FROM SourceDatabase.TableName);
Insert Into TargetDatabase.TableName (SELECT  * FROM SourceDatabase.TableName);
...
Commit

END;
```

How can I write that in a dynamic way that Oracle accepts this statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you really mean "database" in the Oracle definition of the term?  Or do you mean "schema"?  The pseudocode you posted appears to be assuming that `SourceDatabase` and `TargetDatabase` are schemas in a single database.  If you really mean to indicate that they are separate databases, you would needd to use database links to query the remote tables.

Assuming you mean schemas

```
DECLARE
  l_src_schema varchar2(30) := 'Source';
  l_dest_schema varchar2(30) := 'Destination';
  l_sql_stmt varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
  l_sql_stmt := 
    'INSERT INTO ' || l_dest_schema || '.table_name ' ||
    '  SELECT * FROM ' || l_src_schema || '.table_name';
  dbms_output.put_line( 'Preparing to execute: ' || l_sql_stmt;
  execute immediate l_sql_stmt;
END;
```

Note that it's generally a good idea to generate the dynamic SQL statement in a separate variable that you can print out because that makes debugging the code much easier.  Otherwise, if there is an error, there is no way to retrieve the actual SQL statement that your code tried to execute.

Comment: @Lisa - Then you mean "schema".  A schema in Oracle is the set of objects owned by a particular user.

Comment: How do I find out whether my UserId has assigned this schema?

Comment: @Lisa - I'm not sure I understand the question.  Your account can be granted privileges on objects that are in other schemas.  It cannot be granted privileges on other schemas.  The name of a user's schema is the same as the name of the user.  The Oracle user HR, for example, owns all the objects in the HR schema.  You can grant the HR user access to objects in other schemas such as the SCOTT schema.

Comment: Thanks for the great information. I just wonder wether I need a 'commit' within an begin...end ?

Comment: @Lisa - You need a commit if and only if you've completed a logical transaction.  That is determined by the needs of the business, it's not something you can just look at a snippet of code and know.  Generally, you want to put transaction control statements at the highest possible level of your application so that lower-level code can be reused easily.  It's very annoying, for example, to have a stored procedure that includes a commit if I'm trying to write a piece of code that wants to include both whatever the procedure does and some additional work in a single transaction.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to use [`execute immediate`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm).

```
DECLARE
SourceDatabase VARCHAR2(50) := 'DB1';
TargetDatabase VARCHAR2(50) := 'DB2';

BEGIN

execute immediate 'Insert Into '||  TargetDatabase || '.TableName 
                   (SELECT  * 
                      FROM ' || SourceDatabase || '.TableName)';
...
commit;

END;
```

, or explicitly state the DB name.

```
begin

   insert into DB2.TableName select * from DB1.TableName;
   commit;

end;
```